# "auth/user-not-found" when signing in user with Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a firebase app connected to monaca CLI and OnsenUI.  I am trying to create a user and log them in in the same action. **I can successfully create a user**, **but I can't log in.** When I log them in I get the following error

```
auth/user-not-found
```

and

```
There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The User may have been deleted
```

I confirmed that the new user is in the db...Here is my code for the signup and signin

```
//signup function stuff
var login = function() {
  console.log('got to login stuff');
  var email = document.getElementById('username').value;
  var password = document.getElementById('password').value;

  //firebases authentication code
  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    console.log('User did not sign up correctly');
    console.log(errorCode);
    console.console.log(errorMessage);
  });

  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
     console.log(error.code);
     console.log(error.message);
  });

  fn.load('home.html');


};
```

Comment: Creating a user automaticly logs that user in so you don't need to log them in seperatly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a so-called race condition in your flow.

When you call `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` Firebase **starts** creating the user account. But this may take some time, so the code in your browser continues executing.

It immediately continues with `signInWithEmailAndPassword()`. Since Firebase is likely still creating the user account, this call will fail.

The solution in general with this type of situation is to chain the calls together, for example with a `then()`:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(user) {
  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
     console.log(error.code);
     console.log(error.message);
  });
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  console.log('User did not sign up correctly');
  console.log(errorCode);
  console.console.log(errorMessage);
});
```

But as André Kool already commented: creating a user automatically signs them in already, so in this case you can just do:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(user) {
  // User is created and signed in, do whatever is needed
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  console.log('User did not sign up correctly');
  console.log(errorCode);
  console.console.log(errorMessage);
});
```

You'll likely soon also want to [detect whether the user is already signed](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) in when they get to your page. For that you'd use `onAuthStateChanged`. From the docs:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.  I have implemented your changes and no longer am facing the problem.  My next question is how come I get a 'permission denied' error when trying to .push() after. As though my user wasn't signed in

Answer (score 0):

async/await works too.

```
(async () => {

        try {
            const result = await auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
            console.log(result);

        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }

    })()
```